# Twitter Search API posting unwanted string on Rails page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am using the twitter gem and the search api to embed searched tweets on a page, but for some reason, at the bottom of the page, at the end of the embedded tweets, something like this will be posted in plain text:

```
#<Twitter::SearchResults:0x007f893bb766e8>
```

I cannot figure out why this is being posted. Obviously for presentation reasons I do not want this awkwardly affixed to the end of the page.

from **home.html.erb**

```
<ul>
    <% query = params["q"] %>
      <% if query != nil and query.chars.include? "#" %>
        <%= TwitterApi.search_twitter(query).each do |t| %>
          <% tweet = TwitterApi.embed(t)%>
          <%= raw(tweet.html) %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

from **twitter_api.rb**

```
class TwitterApi
    def self.public_tweets(query)
      client.user_timeline(query, count: 1, exclude_replies: true, include_rts: false)
    end

    def self.embed(arg)
      client.oembed(arg)
    end

    def self.search_twitter(query)
      query += " -rt"
      client.search(query, count: 3)
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `=` sign from the `each` line:

instead of:

```
<%= TwitterApi.search_twitter(query).each do |t| %>
```

it should be:

```
<% TwitterApi.search_twitter(query).each do |t| %>
```

`<%=` means that the result of the line is rendered on the page. In case of an `each` clause, the result is the collection being iterated upon, in this case it is the result of `TwitterApi.search_twitter(query)`, which is of type `Twitter::SearchResults`...